# How to use API documentation in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

If i add some jar to my build path and want to see some hints as i type when programming (e.g. parameters and return values of some functions), how can it be achieved?
E.g.  I want some help when using Axis and online documentation is available (http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/index.html).

How to "import" this or any other similiar javadocs into Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the Package Explorer view expand
   your project and its library folder
   for the Axis library.
2. Right-click the Axis jar and select Properties.
3. In the Properties dialog, select
   Javadoc Location in the tree on the
   left.
4. With the Javadoc URL option
   selected, click Browse.
5. Navigate to
   the appropriate folder (see table
   that follows) and click OK twice to
   exit the Properties dialog.

Answer (score 6):

Open the Project Preference and go to Java Build Path. There you can attach javadoc location for every jar you have.

[image]